# In what disk is GRUB located?

Tags: grub2, partitioning

I would like to know, since i'm planning on recreating my partitions to fix some problems, but i would like to really make sure that GRUB deletes along with my partitions, if someone knows where the GRUB files are installed, cause if it is on the Windows partition i would have to abort my plan.

So long story short in what disk are GRUB files located?

My partitions:

F: System Reserved, NTFS File System, 350.00MB Capacity and 203.18MB Used Space. (I'm not really sure but maybe this is the Shadow Storage Disk since i set the maximum space used to around 350MB, but again, i'm not sure)

C: NTFS> Windows 8 Partition
*: Ext4> Linux Mint Partition
*: NTFS> 8.00GB Swap Partition
*: NTFS> Previous Pear OS Partition, I formatted the disk, i'm still not sure if I completelly deleted Pear OS, but it's no longer accessible for sure
D: NTFS> Previous Ubuntu Partition, i uninstalled it temporarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run BootInfoScript (http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/).  The output file (RESULTS.txt) will indicate where grub is located on your machine - something like:

=> Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos5)/boot/grub on this drive.

Comment: Should I run this in Linux or Windows? I suppose Linux since it's a .gz file...

Comment: => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 94 for .

Comment: Is there a way to delete it? @centaurusa ?

Comment: You do not normally delete a boot loader, but just install a new system that will overwrite with its boot loader. Of course if you do not have a system installed, grub will not work. Or you have to repair MBR with an existing system to add its boot loader to MBR.